# Laplace transform, Brownian semigroup

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a question about the Laplace transform of a measure and a semigroup.

Let $(\eta_{t})_{t>0}$ be a family of measures on $(]0,\infty[,\mathcal{B}(]0,\infty[))$.

The Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}\eta_{t}(\lambda)$ of $\eta_{t}$ is the real valued function defined by

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L}\eta_{t}(\lambda)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-\lambda s)\eta_{t}(ds),\quad \lambda>0\cdots(\star)
\end{eqnarray*}

We assume that $\mathcal{L}\eta_{t}(\lambda)=\exp[-t\lambda]\cdots(\star \star)$.

Let $(p_{t})_{t>0}$ be the Brownian semigroup on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, i.e. , for $f$  (Bounded, Borel function)

\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{t}f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)(2 \pi t)^{-1/2} \exp \left[\frac{-|x-y|^{2}}{2t} \right]dy,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{eqnarray*}

I want to show the following equation:
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{t}f=\int_{0}^{\infty}p_{s}f \,\eta_{t}(ds)
\end{eqnarray*}

My process:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}p_{s}f \,\eta_{t}(ds)&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)(2 \pi s)^{-1/2} \exp \left[\frac{-|x-y|^{2}}{2s} \right]dy\, \eta_{t}(ds)\\
&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y) \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty}
 (2 \pi s)^{-1/2} \exp \left[\frac{-|x-y|^{2}}{2s} \right]\, \eta_{t}(ds) \right]dy\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Can I rewrite the following integration in the form of $(*)$?

\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int_{0}^{\infty}
 (2 \pi s)^{-1/2} \exp \left[\frac{-|x-y|^{2}}{2s} \right]\, \eta_{t}(ds) 
\end{eqnarray*}